# Amazon AWS - Get FBA Orders

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm  trying to get all FBA orders from Amazon. The feed I'm currently using is the RequestReport with the report type as “[_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html)"” -

From reading the documentation would I be correct in assuming there is no official way to distinguish between FBA and manufacturer fulfilled orders on this report?

The only way I can see to do this would be to change the program to stop requesting a report and instead request the [ListOrders](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html) feed which allows filtering on the [Fulfillment Channel](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Amazon AWS Support and got the answer I needed

> _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_ report type will return only Merchant Fulfillment Orders. If you want a report type to see all the orders
>   along with FBA orders you can use All order reports. Below is the
>   documentation for All Order reports. Please note that All order
>   reports are only for tracking purpose.
>
> http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderTrackingReports